# Why the new mongo database created is not seen with `show dbs`

Tags: mongodb

I am learning mongoDB and I am at the stage of doing basic operations.

I understand that to create a new db the `use mydatabase` can be used.
I also understand that `show dbs` is used to show a list of the databases.

So I am doing the following:

`use users` - this creates the db called 'users'

`show dbs` - the 'users' database is not showned

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use users` - this alone does **not** create the database. You have to write something to it to make it spring to life.

```
use users
db.foo.insert({a: 1})
```